# How do i apply a link to a td element in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to simple_format(h(post.text)), post  %>
  <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
</td>
```

In rails, how do I make the entire td link to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can report that I have used [@Ribena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713077/ribena)'s suggestion above based on [@Rob Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461347/rob-davis)'s answer and have created a div inside that makes (at least most of) the space in a `<td>` element.

`<td>
      <%= link_to user_url user.id do %>
        <div id="clickable">
           <%= user.name+' == '+user.current_score.to_s %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </td>`

makes the bulk of the white space clickable.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make all of the text in the cell clickable, you could do this:

```
<td>
    <%= link_to post do %>
        <%= simple_format(h(post.text)) %>
        <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>
    <% end %>
</td>
```

which would wrap an `a` tag around both of your text bits.

If you want to make the entire `td` background clickable, you can't just wrap the `td` with an `a` tag since HTML doesn't allow an `a` as a child of a `tr`, and behavior is likely to be inconsistent across browsers. Rails would gladly do it for you (just put the `td` inside the `link_to` block), but it probably wouldn't behave the way you want it to. You'd need different markup.

Comment: So there's no easy way to make the entire td background clickable with rails? What if your link_to block were to wrap around a div containing the post title and timestamp, would the entire td be clickable then? Thanks for your response.